# How can i create an object keys from array values in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key

i am new to javascript and while working on a little project i have a problem ,
i have an array which contains the day splitted into quarters like that

```js
['09:00', '09:15', '09:30', '09:45']
```

i want to create an object with keys that are the values of this array like that :

```js
var obj = {
    '09:00': false , 
    '09:15': true , 
    '09:30': false 
    ....
}
```

but i don't want to do it manually because the object will contain time until 00:00 so i will have to write a lot of code while i think it is possible to do it automatically ,
i tried fromEntries() method but it gives me a list of key value pairs when i want just to set the keys of the object .
Any solution ?

Comment: I don't understand, true and false where did they come from?

Comment: true or false are not the problem i will get them with another method but my question is how to set the values of the array as the keys of the object

Comment: *i tried fromEntries()*. OK , then show what have you tried...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert array values to object keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43137010/convert-array-values-to-object-keys)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simple use a `for-loop` like:

```js
const arr = ['09:00', '09:15', '09:30', '09:45'];
let obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
  obj[arr[i]] = '';

console.log(obj);
```

I don't know the logic of `true` and `false` so i assigned an empty `string`.

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition was good: [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) does the job.

But you have to build an array like this:

```js
[['09:00',true ], ['09:30', true] /*...*/]
```

In order to do this, a simple [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) can help

```js
Object.fromEntries(
    ['09:00', '09:15', '09:30', '09:45'].map(hour=>[hour, true])
)
```

You can replace `true` with `getStatusFromHour(hour)` and then build a function that sets the right boolean to the selected hour.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple for loop and append the data to the object with the required state.
Like:

```js
var arr = ['09:00', '09:15', '09:30', '09:45', '10:00'];
var obj = {};

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  obj[arr[i]] = false;
}
```